# Using WordPress, how do I create a lead web form that does POST server side to a web api?

Tags: wordpress

Is this even possible? My company has literally spent 6 months trying to figure out how to accomplish this task. Many people within the company feel the task is so simple, that it is self evident that wordpress can do this. However, the feature has still not been delivered. Which makes me question whether wordpress has the ability to accomplish this. (obviously we can accomplish in another tech stack, like asp.net, etc. But we need to know if this is technically possible within wordpress)

The page within WordPress needs to contain a form that does both client side and server side validation. The POST to the web api needs to be done server side. 
Any and all help appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Are we making the false assumption that WordPress is capable of this?

Comment: WordPress is just another PHP framework. If you know PHP, you can pull this off. Read the WordPress documentation for specifics (like sending POST requests to an external API) but other than that it's mostly vanilla PHP.

Comment: @cabrerahector, so basically what you are saying is that once we start creating web forms that do POSTS to server side, we have basically entered the world of PHP stack and then are in need of a PHP expert? Correct?

Comment: Oh, and for client-side validation you have JS (there are quite a few libraries out there that can help) or you could use the built-in HTML 5 form fields validation that modern browsers already include. Pick whichever you feel the most comfortable with / fits your project the best and start coding :)

Comment: Yep, WordPress *is* built with PHP so you guys need to know your ways around PHP (or know someone who does). A fullstack developer would be ideal for this as (s)he should be able to do front-end development as well (thus be able to do the whole client-side validation stuff too.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You can make a template for a page with HTML+Java​Script
 code. Make validation in the browser. Then send the data to the server through AJAX and check it. At the end get an answer from server.

Also you can create widget or plugin and paste your form( +validation ) with needed code inside any page of your site through shortcode.

And besides with WordPress REST API you can do server validation on any platform that can work with JSON.

**Edit**

If you need the other pages or any content, you can create server side HTTP POST request via [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or other libraries from PHP. With data taken from front-end form.

But if you don’t need content management system, then using WP doesn't have any sens. Only because of the one form and server code for HTTP POST request.

Comment: false. This fails to accomplish the goal of doing both server side validation and POST from server side.

Comment: @joey Why? What prevents you from checking form at the front-end? Then send data to the server and check there?

Comment: sorry @Rimarx, I should have specified. The POST to the web api needs to be done server side. Its a hard requirement.

Comment: @joey Do you need to take any data from the clients first?

Comment: What do you mean take any data? If you mean do I need the form data to be sent to the web server, yes, of course. Thats the purpose of having a form..

Comment: @joey I edited my answer using what you wrote later